# Nondeterministically interleaving conduit's Sources

Tags: haskell, conduit

I was hoping to see a nondeterministic interleaving operation for sources, with a type signature like

```
interleave :: WhateverIOMonadClassItWouldWant m => [(k, Source m a)] -> Source m (k, a)
```

The use case is that I have a p2p application that maintains open connections to many nodes on the network, and it is mostly just sitting around waiting for messages from any of them. When a message arrives, it doesn't care where it came from, but needs to process the message as soon as possible. In theory this kind of application (at least when used for socket-like sources) could bypass GHC's IO manager entirely and run the `select`/`epoll`/etc. calls directly, but I don't particularly care how it's implemented, as long as it works.

Is something like this possible with conduit? A less general but probably more feasible approach might be to write a `[(k, Socket)] -> Source m (k, ByteString)` function that handles receiving on all the sockets for you.

I noticed the `ResumableSource` operations in conduit, but they all seem to want to be aware of a particular `Sink`, which feels like a bit of an abstraction leak, at least for this operation.

Comment: How much faster perf do you need than the simple solution using forkIO and a Source wrapping a Chan/TChan?

Comment: I don't necessarily need high performance (I anticipate connecting to around 1000 of these peers at the most) but I'm also just generally interested in these iteratee-like abstractions and was wondering whether it was possible to provide this kind of operation with conduits. It seems like a reasonably common use case for certain kinds of network protocols.

Comment: I believe the event manager is about as close as you'll get without using `select` or `epoll` directly or through some package. I don't think there is a polling interface exposed from the event manager (it wouldn't be much of an event manager if it did) so you'd end up with some number of threads and chans with most designs anyways. What I'd do is start with a `Source` wrapping a bounded `TChan`, forking a thread per connection initially. Move to the event manager if it's necessary for performance. If you're still having problems there is always FFI.

Comment: That would work, but if we wanted to go for an approach that avoided the overhead of GHC threads and chans, the GHC event manager does have an API at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/GHC-Event.html.

The real question becomes whether a conduit `Source` can "push" values out or whether a sink conceptually is pulling them out. In the former case, the GHC.Event API could easily allow an efficient `[(k, Socket)] -> Source m (k, ByteString)` combinator. If they're passive, then we'd need to queue up the results.

Comment: If you need to avoid threads and callbacks you're probably going to have to use a poll loop to keep with the `Source` pull model. I'd at least start with the simple approach (forkIO/Chan) to set a benchmark and work from there as necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stm-conduit package provides the [mergeSources](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm-conduit/0.4.1/doc/html/Data-Conduit-TMChan.html#v%3amergeSources) which performs something similar- though not identical- to what you're looking for. It's probably a good place to start.

Comment: Accept Michael's answer.  It does what I described.

Comment: Could anyone elaborate on why the type of `mergeSources` constrains the monad argument of the `Source`s it deals with to be of the form `ResourceT m` instead of any `MonadResource` instance?

Comment: I can't see a reason, it's worth filing an issue with the maintainer. You can likely fix this yourself when calling `mergeSources` by using `hoist liftResourceT`.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSnoyman
I created an issue here: https://github.com/cgaebel/stm-conduit/issues/25
I also was able to figure out an appropriate wrapper following your suggestion that changes the entire type to not explicitly mention `ResourceT`, which meets my needs.

Comment: This is now implemented in stm-conduit 2.5.1.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

You can poll a bunch of `Source`s without blocking by forking threads to poll where in each thread you pair the `Source` up with a `Sink` that sends the output to some concurrency channel:

```
concur :: (WhateverIOMonadClassItWouldWant m) => TChan a -> Sink a m r
```

... and then you define a `Source` that reads from that channel:

```
synchronize :: (WhateverIOMonadClassItWouldWant m) => TChan a -> Source a m r
```

Notice that this would be no different than just forking the threads to poll the sockets themselves, but it would be useful to other users of `conduit` that might want to poll other things than sockets using `Source`s they defined because it's more general.

If you combined those capabilities into one function, then the overall API of the call would look something like:

```
poll :: (WhateverIOMonadClassItWouldWant m) => [Source a m r] -> m (Source a m r)
```

... but you can still throw in those `k`s if you want.